# Order ascending is ignored in meta query?

Tags: wp-query, meta-query, order, pre-get-posts

I'm using [pre_get_posts](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts) to alter my main query and attach a meta query to it. This is on a woocommerce products archive page (...not sure if that would make a difference).

```
function has_upcoming_date( $query ) {
    if( ! is_admin() && $query->is_main_query() && $query->query_vars['product_cat'] == 'wine-classes' ) {
        $meta_query = array(
            'key'=>'wfd_upcoming_booking_date',
            'value'=>'0',
            'compare'=>'>'
        );
        $query->set('meta_query', $meta_query);
        $query->set('posts_per_page', -1);
        $query->set('meta_key', 'wfd_upcoming_booking_date');
        $query->set('orderby', 'meta_value_num');
        $query->set('order', 'ASC');
    }
}

add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'has_upcoming_date', 10000000 );
```

The meta query works well, and filters the posts correctly. The `orderby => meta_value` seems to work as well. But the order isn't changed to ascending.

This is the sql request I can see using Query Monitor:

```
SELECT wp_posts.*
FROM wp_posts 
INNER JOIN wp_term_relationships
ON (wp_posts.ID = wp_term_relationships.object_id)
INNER JOIN wp_postmeta
ON ( wp_posts.ID = wp_postmeta.post_id ) 
INNER JOIN wp_postmeta AS mt1
ON ( wp_posts.ID = mt1.post_id )
WHERE 1=1 
AND ( wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id IN (110) )
AND ( wp_postmeta.meta_key = 'wfd_upcoming_booking_date' 
AND ( ( mt1.meta_key = 'wfd_upcoming_booking_date'
AND CAST(mt1.meta_value AS SIGNED) > '0' ) ) )
AND wp_posts.post_type = 'product'
AND (wp_posts.post_status = 'publish'
OR wp_posts.post_status = 'acf-disabled'
OR wp_posts.post_status = 'private')
GROUP BY wp_posts.ID
ORDER BY wp_postmeta.meta_value+0 DESC, wp_posts.post_date DESC
```

Can anyone tell why this wouldn't be working or where else I should look to diagnose?

Comment: `meta_query` should be an array of arrays - [See Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Custom_Field_Parameters). Maybe trying `'orderby', 'meta_value_num'`.

Comment: not sure if casting as `CHAR` then ordering numerically would be an issue. are you literally saving the string `NULL` as a value?

Comment: @Milo, no, it was saving the null value. But now I've updated it to save the string 0 and `compare => ">"`. Doesn't seem to make a difference.

Comment: @Howdy_McGee I changed the meta query to an array of arrays, and it still filters correctly, but the `order => "ASC"` still isn't respected - using `meta_value` or `meta_value_num`

Comment: have a look at the WP_Query codex page for the `EXISTS` operator, and the array syntax for multiple `orderby` conditions.

Comment: Tried the multiple orderby conditions syntax and still doesn't change the posts being displayed in descending order. The order parameter is being overwritten somewhere before the SQL request, I'm just not sure where to look.

Comment: Set `$query->set( 'suppress_filters', true );` in your `pre_get_posts` action. This will suppress all filters in `WP_Query` which could alter the generated SQL. If this works, you have a bad filter somewhere, probably `posts_clauses` or `posts_orderby`. In your template or header, also do `var_dump( $wp_query->request )`, this will dump the SQL generated by the main query. Also, just do a basic `var_dump( $wp_query )` and inspect the main query in general. Just a note, make sure that you nowhere are using `query_posts`, this can and will break the main query